# enter in textBox

Tags: jquery

Im trying to create functionality in which after user enters "ENTER" button the button is clicked.

What I came to is :

```
$(selector).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        eval($("#" + buttonID).attr('href'));
    }
});
```

it works perfectly but there is one example in which i would like it to behave in different way:

When I start typing letters in my textBox there are hints displayed below (stanard chrome behaviour) so that I can choose one of the previous values typed to the textBox. I choose it and hit enter. At this point I dont want to submit form but it does according to my js code. Is there any way to get rid of such behaviour ?

thanks for help

Comment: does the textbox still technically have focus when the enter key is pressed and the dropdown for hints has appeared?

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI autocomplete for selecting suggested value..?

Comment: No im not using jQuery autocomplete

Comment: @jammypeach- yes I think so, the problem is that I dont want it to :)

Comment: @gruber i was hoping not, as you could have tested for that. i can't think of a way around this unless you can ask the browser if that suggestion box thingy is open or not - there *may* be something in the dev notes, check here:http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/devguide.html

Comment: I added code: if($(document.activeElement).attr("class") == cssClass){
      eval($("#" + buttonID).attr('href'));
     }

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved by using keypress event.